# How can I copy data from one disk to another

Tags: hard-drive

How canI copy the data from one hard-disk to another hard-disk which are connected to the same machine?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Yes it does. Not very well, perhaps, but I think people who would be able to answer the question if it were phrased better will be able to understand it.

Comment: I stared at this question for a while before realizing that Polestar meant "hard drive" not "hardware". Subsequent answers make more sense in this knowledge as well.

Comment: can you clarify more details on what you want to accomplish? it looks like you want drive cloning software, but it's very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Well ... open your favorite file manager, select and copy ... then paste into the the new drive...

Or, do you mean, how to migrate your hole old drive to a new one, including the operating system?

That may be tricky, but [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org) may help you. Connect **only** your existing drive, make a clone, write to one or several DVDs. Now connect your new drive **only** and restore the system.

Comment: I don't understand why one should write a clone to DVDs rather than copy directly from one to the other.

Comment: If you need to migrate your hole operating system from one disk to another ... you can't just copy/paste. There are OS related informations on the HDD you can't see in a file manager. Ans as I said in my first sentence, if you just want to copy some files, than copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

You could download a hard drive copying tool.

Drive manufacturers such as [Seagate offer instructions and downloads for this sort of thing](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/support/downloads/discwizard).

Answer (score 0):

If you need an exact copy and don't want an easy way to do this within Windows look into [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm)  If will allow you to use VSS to make a live copy of the whole disk with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Acronis True Image Home works very well for me in very easy point and click GUI drive cloning under Windows OS -- and [the eval version is free](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/download/) and works 100% for the common "I just bought a new larger drive and I want to clone the smaller drive to it" scenario.

But you didn't specify a host OS in your question..